# Calls to secondary methods failing due to Config.detach() related error

Tags: karate

I have never come across this error before but have seen it for the first time today in various places. I cannot pinpoint any one scenario that causes it. The only commonality I have found is that it occurs right after calling a secondary method in a feature file right after another call read instance.

Looks something like the following:

```
* call read('abc.feature@method') {test: '#(variable)'}

* table random
|order |status |
| '1'  | 200   |

* call read('xyz.feature@method') random

The second instance of call read errors out as:
"com.intuit.karate.core.Config.detach()" because "config" is null
```

In the above scenario, the second call itself fails with that error. Seeing it in three different places now.

Please advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just please upgrade to 1.3.0.RC1 or RC2 and let us know how it goes:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.3.0-Upgrade-Guide